# How do I create a link to a file in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: 23.10

Ubuntu 22.04 had a Create Link option for files and folders that is not in 23.10 so what is the replacement?

Answer (score 2):

The default setting for Gnome is to hide the Create Link option.

It's a setting. You can change it.

1. Open Nautilus.
2. Select the Options (hamburger) menu. Select 'Preferences'.
   Keyboard alternative: Three keys `CTRL + ,`

   [image]
3. Enable 'Create Link'

   [image]

There you go. Now you can create links.

Comment: Thank you, yes now I can create links.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symlink with the command

```
ln -s /path/to/source/file /full/path/to/destination/file
```